# Distribution of string array first character in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string, frequency-distribution

Give an array in PHP with 100,000 string elements, I am looking for a way to count the distribution of the first character in the string.

So essentially the output I am looking for is something like:

```
array(
    0 => 3563,
    1 => 3146,
    ...
    'a' => 3590,
    'b' => 3863,
    ...
    'A' => 3224,
    'B' => 3765
)
```

How is this achieved?

Comment: It should be a straight forward loop through the array, substring and increment operation. What did you try and what problems did you run into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate through with a [`for`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) or [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop:

```
$distribution_count_array = array();
foreach($string_array as $item)
{
    $first_char = substr($item,0,1);
    if(isset($distribution_count_array[$first_char]))
        $distribution_count_array[$first_char] += 1;
    else
        $distribution_count_array[$first_char] = 1;
}
```

and keep count in a separate array, using the first letter as the key.